# how to add gnomon to all your shell commands by default

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

I wanted to pipe all my commands to gnomon by default in zsh.

Like say,
if I give `cd folder`. it should automatically pipe gnomon.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by mentioning that it's a bad idea to redirect *everything* to gnomon. Some commands will not work well with that. Rather, you could create aliases for the commands you really want redirected:

```bash
alias ls='ls | gnomon'
```

or better (supports command line args):

```bash
ls() {
    command ls "$@" | gnomon
}
```

With that said, if you know exactly what you're doing, there is a way in zsh to do some processing every time a command is entered. It's called the [preexec hook](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-preexec_005ffunctions). You would set it up something like this:

```bash
preexec () {
    eval "$3" | gnomon
    exec zsh
}
```

Since the preexec hook isn't meant to modify or cancel commands, the `exec` line will prevent the regular command execution by restarting zsh before it has a chance to execute your command the second time (without the pipe).

***Warning**: The `preexec` hack is a brute force approach and only included here for didactic purposes. For all intents and purposes this does a shell restart, not a continuation - environment variables are lost, settings are reset, child processes will go sideways, it may not even be the same shell if you have multiple zsh versions installed, etc.*

Comment: You should note that `exec zsh` does not start a new shell whose state is equivalent to the previous shell, though, only one initialized using the OP's configuration files. It's a fragile simulation of what you intend.

Comment: @chepner Absolutely, this is an illustration and not a working solution. I'll add more detail to the warning.